# Why calling setenv("OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE", "disable", 1) does not affect logging?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, environment-variables, setenv

Overly verbose logs produced by 3rd party libraries can be hidden in Swift by setting `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environmnet variable to `disable` in your run scheme - as shown on the image below.

That silences all `NSLog` output from your app. I want to disable it only for certain calls. I tried to set the environment variable like this:

```
setenv("OS_ACTIVITY_MODE", "disable", 1)
```

And like this

```
putenv(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: ("OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable" as NSString).utf8String))
```

The environment is changed as verified by calling `print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment)` but there unlike specifying it in XCode run scheme, the logs are not affected.

Why doesn't it work and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/loading-credentials-from-env-variables/12631 I think you will find an answer here.

Comment: @AisultanAskarov Thanks for the pointer but can you be more specific. There is a lot of information in the threadth.

Comment: @Rasto If you want to handle [Customizing Logging Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/customizing_logging_behavior_while_debugging) you can find valuable info on link.

Answer (score 4):

When you set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to `disable`, you disable all log outputs for processes that have access to this environment variable, for example the simulators.

When you set the value to either `info` or `debug` it enables the corresponding logging mode unless it is *disabled* in the logging preferences for certain log categories.

So in order to enable only a certain log category, you have to *enable* OS_ACTIVITY_MODE, that is, set it either to `info` or `debug` or leave it at the default, and then *disable* logging for all other categories.

For more information how to do this see the man page for log, type `man log` in the console.

#### Get the current log preferences for simulators:

In the console type:
`xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --status`

That basically means: apply `log config -status` to all booted simulators.

This may print the following to your console:

```
System mode = INFO STREAM_LIVE PRIVATE_DATA
```

#### Get the status for a certain category and subsystem

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --status --subsystem com.mycompany.myapp --category network
```

This may print the below to the console:

```
Mode for 'com.mycompany.myapp(network)'  INFO PERSIST_DEFAULT
```

#### Get Help

For help, the tools `xcrun simctl` and `log` have nifty man pages and help pages.

For example:
type `log config --help` into the console, it prints:

```
usage: log config [options] --mode <modes>
   or: log config [options] --status
   or: log config [options] --reset

description:
    Read or configure settings for the logging system. Configuration
    can act system-wide; or on a subsystem, category, or process level.

options:
    --category <name>             Get/set settings for a given category
    --mode <modes>                Enable given modes
    --process <pid> | <name>      Get/set settings for a given process
    --reset                       Reset settings to defaults
    --status                      Show current settings
    --subsystem <name>            Get/set settings for a given subsystem

modes:
    Modes can be specified as a comma-separated list of key:value pairs.
    Valid keys and their values are:

    level                         off | default | info | debug
    persist                       off | default | info | debug
    stream                        live | default
```

#### Set the log level for a specific subsystem and category

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:debug" --subsystem com.mycompany.myapp --category network
```

Get the status again for this sybsystem and category will print:

```
Mode for 'com.mycompany.myapp(network)'  DEBUG PERSIST_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 3):

Because environment variables are usually read only once, when the program starts.

In libdispatch 442.1.4, the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` variable is read in [`_voucher_init`](https://github.com/aosm/libdispatch/blob/ec3d1496203b87a2280df04bb1be46b34fea7a71/src/voucher.c#L784-L796) to determine a value of an internal variable; `_voucher_init` is in turn called in [`libdispatch_init`](https://github.com/aosm/libdispatch/blob/ec3d1496203b87a2280df04bb1be46b34fea7a71/src/queue.c#L961), which is called only once at program startup. Interestingly, I cannot find this code in later versions of the library; perhaps it has been moved somewhere else. But it doesn’t really matter; the same principle applies. Setting the value of an environment variable will usually have no effect on already-initialised code, and can only be used to influence child processes.

As for solutions, I don’t have an easy one. Personally, I would try finding some method to disable logging in the specific library in question, or to filter the messages out: in the worst case, I’d put a couple of my own `NSLog` calls with messages controlled by me before and after calls to the library, and tell a filter to ignore everything between the two.