# Adding launch argument for all targets

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to disable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` for all targets in my project. The project has multiple targets. What I can do is to go to Edit Scheme->Arguments, and to add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disabled` for specific action (run, archive etc) but only per target. How I would do the same for all targets at once for Run action (on a project level)?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is setting the environment variable programmatically with `setenv` on early start of your app i.e. in `main.swift`  file. You can add main.swift to your project if you don't have one (you should remove @UIApplicationMain from your AppDelegate class).

```swift
//  main.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

setenv("OS_ACTIVITY_MODE", "disable", 1)

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

Comment: Well, I have added main.swift, removed @UIApplicationMain from app delegate, put a break point in main.swift, but logs still show... Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/66221181/3402095 why setenv doesn't really have an effect in this way

Comment: @Whirlwind directions on setting up you main.swift can be found here:
 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-subclass-uiapplication-using-uiapplicationmain

After that this answer should work for you.